# Using for-loop for choosing from specified list (no while-loops)

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I wish to perform the same with `for` loops

```
menu=['salad','becon','pizza','burger','fries']

choosen_menu=''
while choosen_menu not in menu:
    print('choose something')
    choosen_menu= input()
    if choosen_menu == 'None':
        print('not hungry')
        break
else:
    print('the {} is arriving'.format(choosen_menu))
```

Comment: Why use  a for loop here? for loops expect a start and end whereas you can keep asking until the input is correct using a while loop

Comment: `for` loops are really for when you want to iterate over a collection of things. There's ways of turning a `for` loop into essentially a `while True:` loop, but there isn't anything to gain by making that change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while loop seems conceptually right for your use case, but if you really want to, you can transform it to this equivalent for loop:

```
from functools import partial
menu = {'salad', 'bacon', 'pizza', 'burger', 'fries'}
for chosen in iter(partial(input, 'choose something\n'), 'None'):
    if chosen in menu:
        print('the {} is arriving'.format(chosen))
        break
else:
    print('not hungry')
```

This uses some advanced concepts like the two-argument form of `iter()`, which is rarely used, and the `partial` functor for partially applying a function, so the only thing this achieves is making the code harder to read. Otherwise it does more or less exactly the same as your original version, with the same usability issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest using `for loop` for your case, but this will give you what you want:

```
from itertools import count
menu=['salad','becon','pizza','burger','fries']

choosen_menu=''


for i in count(0):
    print('choose something')
    choosen_menu= input()
    if choosen_menu == 'None':
        print('not hungry')
        break
    elif choosen_menu not in menu:
        pass
    else:
        print('the {} is arriving'.format(choosen_menu))
        break
```

Comment: @Kowalski Can you see the edit? I think it's good now.

Comment: This will loops 100 times for maximum. In the code of OP, it *may* loop forever. Also this is an example of why we should not use for loop here and should use while instead.

Comment: Decrementing when entering something not in the menu will give an infinite loop?

Comment: Look carefully on this part: `while choosen_menu not in menu:`.

Comment: I know that the best to use is while, but the OP wants to use for loop instead.

Comment: @AdityaMishra I edit it to make it an infinite loop, take a look.

Comment: @AdityaMishra In the edit I used `i=i-i` instead of `i=i-1`

Comment: @Kowalski see my final edit and tell me if it is now an infinite loop, please.

Comment: This doesn't make the loop infinite. The loop iterates over the range, and reassigning the loop variable inside the loop doesn't change this in any way.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yeah, you are right! I improved my answer now, can you give me your opinion?

Comment: @SvenMarnach I was confusing the basics of python with other programming languages.

Comment: @YounessSaadna seems infinite to me :D